# What are P.SE's new user limitations?

Tags: support, new-users, quality

Short version: Does P.SE have similar new user limitations as SO does?

Buried in the MSO FAQ is this answer about [new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89241/194162).  And it states that new users are only allowed 6 questions in a 24 hour period at a maximum rate of one question every 20 minutes.

However, I have noticed many new users ask 3 questions and then stop.  Is there a different limiter in place for P.SE?

Comment: The restrictions are (vaguely) documented in the privileges page: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user

Answer (score 4):

In many cases where one sees the "3 answers and stop" there is the additional bit of these three questions become significantly downvoted.  The mystical question ban calculation then kicks in before the new user limiter and bans them from asking questions.

This is more obvious on sites where there is a lower flow of questions, active voters, and a higher variability of quality.  Several poor questions in succession are quite likely to gain attention and get all of them downvoted before one can ask 6 questions in the time period.

On sites with a larger traffic flow, it is possible for poor questions to sit around at 0 for awhile until the 6 question limit kicks in.

Answer (score 3):

As far I know the new user restrictions are the same network wide.